# Haskell list of pairs to pairs of lists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, tuples

I have seen here, that there are several approaches to solve it, but I am struggling to solve it with recursion.

Example:  [("a",1), ("b",2)] to (["a","b"] ,[1,2])

I have so far:

```
listOfPairs :: [ ( String , Int ) ] -> ( [ String ] , [ Int ] )
listOfPairs((a,b): xs) = ([a], [b]) -- and here I don't know how to call the function again with the rest xs
```

I have tried `listOfPairs((a,b): xs) = ([a], [b]) + listOfPairs xs` but obviously it doesn't work.

Maybe someone has an idea.
Thank you

Comment: Minor note: there is no need to specify the signature using the `String` and `Int` types. The signature could be: `[(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the idea behind [**`unzip`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unzip)ping:

```
listOfPairs :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
listOfPairs = unzip
```

As for a recursive approach, you should make a recursive call and then append the elements to the the two items of the 2-tuple, so:

```
listOfPairs :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
listOfPairs [] = …
listOfPairs ((a, b):xs) = (a : …, b : …)
    where ~(as, bs) = listOfPairs …
```

Where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.